# This is a large pull request. Large pull requests can only be viewed by loading files individually

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I recently installed `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0` in my app and created small line of codes of `vue components` and `blade.php` files.

When I tried pushing my changes and created a pull request, it gives me error saying `This is a large pull request. Large pull requests can only be viewed by loading files individually.`

I noticed that most of the files came from `vendor` directory caused by installing `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`.

Obviously, it is impossible to **load the files individually** since its almost 2000 files.

Is there anyway to merge this to master? If yes, how?

Comment: You shouldn't be committing folders like `vendor` anyway, your build system should restore such packages.

Answer (score 1):

It only says `can only be viewed` and not `can only be merged`